# What's the type of a mixin class

Tags: typescript

I cannot figure out how to get the type of a typescript mixin class without resorting so some hack (exemplified below)

```
type Constructor<T = {}> = new(...args: any[]) => T;

function MyMixin<T extends Constructor>(BaseClass: T) {
  return class extends BaseClass {doY() {}}
}

// Option A: Ugly/wasteful
const MixedA = MyMixin(class {doX() {}});
const dummy = new MixedA();
type MixedA = typeof dummy;

class OtherA {
  field: MixedA = new MixedA();
  a() {this.field.doX(); this.field.doY();}
}

// Option B: Verbose
class Cls {doX() {}}
interface MixinInterface {doY(): void}

const MixedB = MyMixin(Cls);
type MixedB = Cls & MixinInterface;

class OtherB {
  field: MixedB = new MixedB();
  a() {this.field.doX(); this.field.doY();}
}
```

It's really sad to me that typescript doesn't support honest mixins/traits, but is there some other way to declare the type of `field` without resorting to typeof an instance or having to re-declare the signatures in an interface (I tried `typeof(new MixedBaseA())` but typeof doesn't accept arbitrary expressions)?

Comment: This is different from what is suggested on https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html, for example `class SmartObject implements Disposable, Activatable`

Comment: They introduced support for mixin classes in 2.2 [1]. I don't think the doc is up to date
(1: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-2.html)

Comment: @sky don't use an annotation then. You don't need one. Let the compiler infer the type

Comment: @AluanHaddad That is ok in the example given, but in a more complex setting where I need to instantiate the field in the constructor (because it depends on some constructor parameter for example), not specifying the type would lead tsc to infer `any` instead of the mixin class type

Comment: @sky that's a good point. However, if the constructor parameter is captured as a field as well you can reference it in a field initializer

Answer (score 4):

Probably not what you want, but here's a less wasteful alternative. Given the definition:

```
type Constructor<T = {}> = new(...args: any[]) => T;

function MyMixin<T extends Constructor>(BaseClass: T) {
    return class extends BaseClass {
        doY() { }
    }
}

const MixedA = MyMixin(class { doX() {} });
```

You can get the type using:

```
function getReturnType<R>(fn: (new(...args: any[]) => R)): R {
  return {} as R;
}

const dummy = getReturnType(MixedA);
type MixedAType = typeof dummy;

const mixedA : MixedAType = new MixedA();
mixedA.doX();
mixedA.doY();
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Constructor%3CT%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3E%20%3D%20new(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20T%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20MyMixin%3CT%20extends%20Constructor%3E(BaseClass%3A%20T)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20class%20extends%20BaseClass%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20doY()%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22in%20Y%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20MixedA%20%3D%20MyMixin(class%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20doX()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22in%20X%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20getReturnType%3CR%3E(fn%3A%20(new(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20R))%3A%20R%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20%7B%7D%20as%20R%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20dummy%20%3D%20getReturnType(MixedA)%3B%0D%0Atype%20MixedAType%20%3D%20typeof%20dummy%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20mixedA%20%3A%20MixedAType%20%3D%20new%20MixedA()%3B%0D%0AmixedA.doX()%3B%0D%0AmixedA.doY()%3B)

Proposal for getting the type of any expression is still open for discussion: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6606. This will get rid of the dummy variable and the function.

Or, to get a clean `type MixedAType = MyMixinY & X`, you can choose to return the correct constructor type in the mixin:

```
type Constructor<T = {}> = new(...args: any[]) => T;

interface MyMixinY {
    doY()
} 

function MixinY<T extends Constructor>(BaseClass: T)
    : Constructor<MyMixinY> & T {

    return <any> class Y extends BaseClass implements MyMixinY {
        doY() { 
            console.log("in Y");
        }
    }
}

const MixedA = MixinY(class X {
    doX() {
        console.log("in X");
    }
});

function getReturnType<R>(fn: (new(...args: any[]) => R)): R {
  return {} as R;
}

const dummy = getReturnType(MixedA);
type MixedAType = typeof dummy; // now is `type MixedAType = MyMixinY & X`

const mixedA: MixedAType = new MixedA();
mixedA.doX();
mixedA.doY();
```

Comment: Slick, thanks. That would indeed be much better if `MixedA` has an heavy constructor/instance

Comment: Added another sample where `MixedAType` is resolved to `type MixedAType = MyMixinY & X`, which should help IntelliSense. So it should say `MyMixinY.doY() : any` instead of `(anonymous class)<typeof(anonymous class)>.doY() : any`